# Where can I change the Asp.net MVC 3 Razor syntax highlighting in VS10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax-highlighting, razor

I searched Tools > Options, but where in VS10 can I turn off or change the default highlighting for the new Razor view on the @nuggets in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: It is hard for my eyes for some reason, just personal issue.

Comment: related [Highlighting kill my Razor syntax in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564695/highlighting-kill-my-razor-syntax-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Razor only adds one entry to Fonts & Colors, "Razor Code". That controls the background color given to Razor Code nuggets.  The rest of the colors are the same as the C#/VB colors. The "@" character itself and Razor keywords like "model" and "section" use the same color as the ASPX "<%" tag ("HTML Server-Side Script", thanks to another [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524621/andrew) for digging up the specific entry).

If you'd rather we had separate entries for some of these, please email us and suggest that: razorvs@microsoft.com

Comment: Slight clarification - the `@` and other keywords were the `HTML Server-Side Script` entry under Fonts and Colors.  I had a hard time finding it.

Comment: Edited and credited :). Thanks for closing the loop and posting a comment!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to fix a darker theme =) ... thanks

Comment: Don't forget to restart VS after you have made the change.

Comment: VS2013 appears to have change this from "Razor Code" to "HTML Server Code Block Background".

Comment: In my VS 2013, after changing this 'HTML Server Code...', the razor file didn't re-highlight until I scrolled the relevant section out of view and back again, just a caveat in case it doesn't seem to work on yours either!

Comment: Visual Studio's options were showing me a background colour that did not match the one actually used in the editor; that is, it was lying to me. This was confusing as the colour in the Options dialogue was the one I actually wanted to use. So I had to set it to a dummy colour, apply the change, then reset it to my intended colour.

Comment: @nicodemus13 I have the opposite problem. The highlighting is lost when scrolling the window in VS2015.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, it's also `HTML Server-Side Script`. What a non-intuitive name! >:-6

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting for razor is based on the c#/VB default highlighting. So you'll have to change those settings to see any changes in a cshtml file highlighting. Might be a good feature request...I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

### In Visual Studio 2015

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Font and colors

The name of the property is `HTML Razor Code Background` Change the Item background to the color you like.