# Highlighting kills my Razor syntax in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, themes, syntax-highlighting

I'm using [Expression](http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme) theme in `Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate` on `Windows 7` operating system. (**Note**: Actually, I'm not sure this problem occurs because of the dark theme) A few days ago, I decided to learn `ASP.NET MVC 4` and tried to create a small web application. In Visual Studio, I followed this instruction and created a new asp.net mvc 4 web application: `File->New->Project->ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application.`

Everything was perfect. But when I opened the `Login.cshtml` file, I couldn't even see the razor syntax (expressions which started `@`) because of highlighting. Take a look:

[image]

Even if I select all the text with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in Visual Studio, I barely see the syntax.

[image]

Because of that, I can't even start to learn asp.net mvc. I started to look for a solution for this situation on the internet, but I couldn't find any useful answer. In Visual Studio, I looked the `Tools->Option->Font and Colors` option, but I couldn't find anything for this either. This problem shows only when I'm working in a `View` (for the `Razor`). There is no highlighting problem in `Model`, `Controller` or any other code files.

User ray247 asked a question close enough to my question called [Where can I change the Asp.net MVC 3 Razor syntax hightlighting in VS10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696102/where-can-i-change-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-syntax-hightlighting-in-vs10) but I still can't find a solution. I don't want to stop using my dark theme. It's really good for my eyes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should be able to change the text background for Razor code by:

1. Opening Visual Studio Options (Under `Tools` -> `Options`),
2. Selecting "`Fonts and Colors`" (Under Environment in the treeview at left)
3. Changing the dropdown box at top to "`Text Editor`" (if that isn't the value already),
4. Choosing "`Razor Code`" from the "`Display Items`" listbox, and
5. Changing the background color to your liking and clicking "`OK`" to apply the change.

There's also an "HTML Server-Side Script" setting that controls the background color of the Razor code delimiters (the `@` expression and similar expressions that mark the beginnings of code blocks.)

HTH,
Clay

Comment: Thanks. That's weird because VS 2010 disable the Item color in Razor code section.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Foreground syntax highlighting is great, but highlighting a whole line, just distracts the eye - imho

Comment: In spanish, the item to search is "Fondo de código Razor HTML", I used RCB(50, 50, 50) with the dark theme of visual studio 2013 and it worked perfect.

Comment: For whoever reads this. In Visual Studio 2013 the setting isn't called Razor Code. It's called HTML Razor Code Background.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 it also called   HTML Razor Code Background

Comment: If you want it to match the 'Dark theme colour', change the rgb to 30,30,30