# How do you turn off Razor highlighting in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I found a thread: [Highlighting kills my Razor syntax in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564695/highlighting-kill-my-razor-syntax-in-visual-studio-2010) ,
asking and explaining how to turn off the highlighting for Razors code.

The problem is, I navigate to: `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors` but the razor option isn't there!

I'm sure I can get used to it, but its rather distracting because I'm still very new with MVC.

**This are the options I have:**
[image: An example of what I'm seeing with the highlighting and the options]

(the picture didn't come out as clear as I thought it would, but the Razor options aren't there!)

Comment: There is one called "HTML Razor Code Background" which you could try

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have to find `Tools -> Options ->Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> HTML Razor Code Background` to change it in VS 2013.

Comment: Ohh! There we go! Thank you so much, can carry on with my project now!

Comment: Also valid for VS 2015

Comment: Also valid for VS 2017

Comment: Also valid for VS 2019 Preview

Comment: To complete this answer, you need to change the `Item background` to a color. Since I had a black theme black worked well and was easy to read. If using the standard white theme try the white color.

Comment: I can't find that `HTML Razor` setting in `Fonts and colors` - has it been moved in VS 2019 16.5?

Comment: For some reason with Blazor, in VS 2022, it was `Razor C# Code Transition`

Answer (score 9):

Although the instructions on the accepted answer takes you to the correct settings that needs to be adjusted, it took a while for me to adjust the settings. So for those like me, the key is to change the `Item Background` property of the `HTML Razor Code Background`, but the background color you need to choose should be the same as that of `Plain Text` (the first item in Display Items list). Since I use dark theme, that default color of `Plain Text` wasn’t available for `HTML Razor Code Background`. So I had to go `Custom…` copy the color settings from `Plain Text`, and then got `HTML Razor Code Background`, `Custom…` and plugin those color setting number and now that highlight is gone!

Comment: Or you could just select Automatic and it 'automatically' changes to match the theme background you are currently using..

Answer (score 4):

Please see option that starts with HTML (i know its not obvious but does the trick).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Combining Mateusz Rogulski & goku_da_master's answers, this worked for me:

1. Go to `Tools -> Options ->Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> HTML Razor Code Background`
2. For a dark theme, change `Item background` to `Black`, if it isn't already
3. For a dark theme, change `Item foreground` to `White`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Mateusz Rogulski & goku_da_master's answers, if you select Automatic for the Item background instead of Black (for dark theme), the setting will continue to work if you change the VS theme.