# Razor Syntax Highlighting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

I have a fairly large ASP MVC project which I am running in visual studio 15.4.5.  Whenever I view .cshtml files Visual Studio incorrectly highlights the file for example:

[image]

- We are making use of compiled razor views.
- The project compiles and runs correctly

## What I've tried

- Deleting all bin, obj & .vs folders
- Running .\devenv.exe /ResetUserData
- Running .\devenv.exe /UpdateConfiguration & .\devenv.exe /ClearCache

Comment: close all open documents and reopen them? what extensions are you using?

Comment: @AshleyMedway No extensions and reopening the documents makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tried the `/SafeMode` flag?

Comment: @AshleyMedway No luck I'm afraid.

Comment: `Build > Rebuild Solution` this kind of stuff is really a guessing game.

Comment: Repair the Visual Studio installation using the Visual Studio Installer. `15.5` was just released yesterday.

Comment: `Run as Administrator` typically a fix for most Visual Studio issues.

Comment: I am able to force mine to have problems by changing build configuration Debug to Release, or vice versa, then a build resolves the issue.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I'm afraid updating to 15.5, running as administrator and flicking between release and debug mode has had no effect.

Another dev on the team has started having the exact same issues.

Comment: Does it fix by adding a `@using whatever.namespace` if so try adding that to the local web.config

Comment: @AshleyMedway The namespace is already in the web.config and I've tried including it manually.

Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: That's alright we've all been there, at this point I'm thinking delete the project and get it again from your favourite source control system. So completely remove all trace of the solution and project then checkout to a differently name folder so no caching can interfere

Comment: @AshleyMedway, In the end, I just reformatted the pc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this question whilst trying to solve the nuisance that is the highlighting myself so thought I'd share my findings. Apparently this is the intentional behaviour as it referred to as "Razor Syntax Highlighting" and through both [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0f1829c-eff7-44d9-a156-3ff98503c598/disable-highligthing-in-cshtml?forum=vssetup) on MSDN and another question on here: [How do you turn off Razor highlighting in VS 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404294/how-do-you-turn-off-razor-highlighting-in-vs-2013) I was able to determine how to turn it off on my machine.

**Quote from MSDN post:**

> This highlighting is the built in support for Razor syntax highlighting. If you do not like it, you can open your .cshtml files in Visual Studio using the HTML editor

**Screenshot of what I changed that worked for me:**

[image: screenshot of options dialog]

Comment: This helped me SO MUCH! Thank you!