# How do I turn off Visual Studio background highlighting for the at-symbol (@) in a Razor file?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I've already followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404294/how-do-you-turn-off-razor-highlighting-in-vs-2013), but that still leaves all the `@` symbols and the `@code{}` blocks highlighted, which I find annoying and ugly.

I assume there's a setting in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the `HTML Server-Side Script` display item in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`