# How do I turn off web essentials' razor highlighting?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I just installed Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2. Ever since I installed it, the C# in cshtml files is highlighted white. I have a dark theme. So, since the text is also white, it's unreadable. The theme I'm using is here: https://studiostyl.es/schemes/eye-friend

I looked in the web essentials section of my options and couldn't find anything pertaining to text highlighting. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2 installed.

How do I turn off the highlighting?

Comment: I don't think it's possible according to the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4696982/1523400)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imported the settings of your color schema and got this on one of my cshtml files
[image]

Then, I went to:
Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and colors

Looked for "HTML Server Code Block Background" and changed its background color for a dark one.

Accepted changes, reopened the cshtml files and got this instead:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: On mine the item was "HTML Razor Code Background" but your answer led me right there.

Comment: Wow, that was worth 100 points? lol. Anyway Type `Fonts and colors` into the Quick Launch bar to quickly get to the option

Answer (score 0):

You can change the highlighting color to the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue with Visual Studio's 2013 default Dark theme. However, if I go to

```
Tools - Options - General
```

and switch the theme to Light, or Blue then click OK and then change the theme back to Dark the highlighting corrects itself.